# Probability Sum

Tags: probability, decision-trees

A purchasing agent must decide to accept or reject an incoming
shipment of machine parts. The agent wishes to do either of the
following:
a1: Accept the shipment
a2: Reject the shipment
The fraction of defective parts in the shipment is either 0.1 or 0.5
with a prior likelihood of each occurring being 0.5. The costs
associated with the possible decisions are €1500 if a 0.1 shipment
is rejected and €1000 if a 0.5 shipment is accepted. No costs are
incurred if a 0.1 shipment is accepted or a 0.5 shipment is rejected.
It is possible to test one part from a shipment as a cost of €10.

(iii) Determine the optimal strategy, that is, what action to
take in response to sample outcomes. Show the results of
workings on a decision tree.

Decision Tree: [image]
[image]
[image]

I'm having trouble getting the third part and I don't know where they go the answer from.

Probability of shipment 1 given test result Ok =
where did they get these figures from and how did they do it.
 0.17 0.64
 0.83 0.36

Hope you can help thank you.

Comment: I just added relevant tag. Now I'm trying to understand what is the question. am I right to say that if shipment accepted there is 50% chance for -1000. and if shipment rejected there is 50% for -1500 ?

Comment: yes. I don't understand how he go the probability of shipment : 0.17 0.64 0.83 0.36   What two figures did he multiply and divide by to get those answers

Comment: he just devided as he claims he did : $0.17 = 0.05/0.3$, $0.64 = 0.45/0.7$

Comment: ok but you dont get 0.17 when you divide 0.05 by 0.3?

Comment: typo. should be 0.3. he rounded the results. 0.3 is $P(O_1)$

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They merely applied the formula that they stated,

$$
P(\theta_j\mid O_k)=\frac{P(\theta_j\cap O_k)}{P(O_k)}\;,
$$

which is the standard formula for the conditional probability. For instance, for $j=k=1$,

$$
P(\theta_1\mid O_1)=\frac{P(\theta_1\cap O_1)}{P(O_1)}=\frac{0.05}{0.3}=\frac16\approx0.17\;,
$$

where $P(\theta_1\cap O_1)=0.05$ is taken from the previous table and $P(O_1)=0.3$ is stated to the right of that table.